# Is there a way to access values from the Actions tab in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, storybook, chromatic

I'm using Chromatic to run interaction tests.  When I click the button for "Mexican" cuisine, it appends to the url params.  Storybook reflects this in the "Actions" tab (shown below).  How can I access those Actions so that I can run an assertion against them?

```
  play: async ({canvasElement}) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);
    userEvent.click(await canvas.findByRole('button', {name: 'Mexican'}));
    // expect that nextRouter.push is called with the value "?cuisineOption=MEXICAN"
  },
```

[image: Actions]

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no first-class way to do this in Storybook.  I was able to get this very hacky solution to work for me:

```
let pushCalls: any[][] = [];
const afterEach = () => {
  pushCalls = [];
};
const channel = addons.getChannel();
channel.on(FORCE_REMOUNT, afterEach);
channel.on(STORY_RENDER_PHASE_CHANGED, ({newPhase}) => {
  if (newPhase === 'loading') afterEach();
});
```

Then in your component you can mock the router like so:

```
  parameters: {
    nextjs: {
      router: {
        push: (...args: any[]) => {
          action('nextRouter.push')(...args);
          pushCalls.push(args);
          return Promise.resolve(true);
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Then you can create assertions:

```
expect(pushCalls[0][0]).toEqual('/?cuisineOption=MEXICAN');
```

Comment: Hi! I'm facing the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77240899/how-can-i-assert-that-a-storybook-action-was-fired/77328897
It seems like you haven't found any other solution to this yet, right?

Comment: That's correct.  This method looks ugly, but has been working reliably for me.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used Chromatic, so I can't attest to whether or not it exposes the controls, actions, etc... but I think you can get the same results by mocking `nextRouter` and asserting that some route object matches the value you expect when the button is clicked.

You can probably use `next-router-mock` for this which can be find [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-router-mock)

Here's an example of how that might work:

```
import { within, userEvent } from '@storybook/testing-library';
import { expect } from '@storybook/jest';
import mockRouter from 'next-router-mock';

jest.mock('next/router', () => require('next-router-mock'));

export const MyTask = {
  play: async ({canvasElement}) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);
    userEvent.click(await canvas.findByRole('button', {name: 'Mexican'}));    

    // router matches the expected value: "?cuisineOption=MEXICAN"
    expect(mockRouter).toMatchObject({ 
      asPath: "/?cuisineOption=MEXICAN",
      pathname: "/",
      query: { cuisineOption: "Mexican" },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @jmargolisvt This code was just an example pattern of how you might encorporate `next-router-mock`. Did you follow the link to their documentation to see if there was any more config you might need to get this working with storybook?

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work.  Thanks, though.