# How can I assert that a Storybook action was fired?

Tags: storybook, nextjs-storybook

I'm using Storybook to write interaction tests for my Next.js/React components. I'm using the `@storybook/nextjs` addon which is great because it automatically [applies actions to the mocked router's methods](https://storybook.js.org/blog/integrate-nextjs-and-storybook-automatically/#actions).

> One of the most significant pieces of Next.js is the router, which handles navigation and prefetching of page data. This framework will mock all of the necessary routing contexts in your Storybook, for both next/router and next/navigation.

I have a component that calls `router.push()` on change. I can visually confirm the `nextRouter.push` action is logged in the Storybook server's console.

[image: nextRouter.push action is logged]

Is there a way to programatically assert that the action was fired? This way the assertion could be part of the interaction test and I could run it in the CI. Currently I'm using Cypress end-to-end tests to express such test scenarios.

It feels like it should be possible, but I'm unable to achieve it.

```js
export const Default: Story = {
    play: async (args) => {
        const canvas = within(args.canvasElement);
        fireEvent.change(canvas.getByTestId('my-component')}, {
            target: { value: 'AMSTERDAM' },
        });
        const routerPush = action('nextRouter.push');
        expect(routerPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/stays/amsterdam');
    },
};
```

However, this results in an error:

```
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

Comment: I've just found that the same question was asked before on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76738952/is-there-a-way-to-access-values-from-the-actions-tab-in-storybook

Answer (score 0):

I Would've comment this if I was able to comment.. anyways :

Since you're using Cypress you could simply `visit` the storybook's url and then start your tests from there..

I don't know if that would be possible I don't have the setup to try it myself but I think it costs nothing to try !

```js
cy.visit(`{STORYBOOK_URL}/...`);
cy.get(..) // get the action button glhf lol
cy.get('button[..]').click();
cy.get('.os-content').should('contain', 'the-my-component-event');
```

That's the only idea i've from now, with that, you're covering storybook !

> I've based my naming over the styling of this storybook

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, my point is exactly not to use Cypress but replace some of our e2e tests with lower level component tests by Storybook.

Comment: Aaah oups didnt understand that, i'm not sure you're able then.. i'm not used to using Storybook, good luck in your project !

Answer (score 0):

using the same addons as you are moking what next.js needs.
Making use of Storybook parameters, i made a mock for the push method:

```js
export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.parameters = {
  nextRouter: {
    pathname: '/profile/[id]',
    asPath: '/profile/lifeiscontent',
    query: {
      id: 'lifeiscontent',
    },
    push: (url, as) => {
      console.log('Navigating to ', url);
      action('router.push')(url, as);
    },
  },
};
```

So i take action function from a @storybook/addons to create the log

now in the interation test:

```js
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

export const Default: Story = {
  play: async (args) => {
    const canvas = within(args.canvasElement);
    fireEvent.click(canvas.getByTestId('my-component')});
    
    const routerPush = action('router.push');
    expect(routerPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/expected-url');
  },
};
```

I'm using Jest `toHaveBeenCalledWith` function to assert that `router.push` should be called correctly.

Comment: thanks for looking into this issue! 

Where do I put the first block of code? It's unclear to me.

Where does `router.push` come from? In the Storybook console, it logs `nextRouter.push`.

Also, the doc says "[the Sorybook next.js integration] will mock all of the necessary routing contexts in your Storybook, for both next/router and next/navigation." It gives me the idea that no explicit mocking is needed.

Comment: @viam0Zah  In this case, i made a custom mock for the push method so that we can understand where and when it is called and when the interation we needs occours

Comment: I'm trying to make sense out of your code but I'm unable to use it. Where does the `Template` binding come from? Also in your example you describe `Default` twice.

Comment: **FYI: It is not working, [read more here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/16941)** <-@viam0Zah this might help you